# Apply GridSearchCV for two algorithms having common hyperparameters

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, random-forest, grid-search

I am working on a regression task and using a Stacking regressor model.

```
estimators = [
    ('abr', AdaBoostRegressor(base_estimator=None)),
    ('gbr', GradientBoostingRegressor()),
    ('rfr', RandomForestRegressor()),
    ('xgbr', XGBRegressor())
]
```

I have a bunch of regressors in it and want to use GridSearchCV to find the best parameters. For this, I have to pass a dictionary of parameter values to GridSearchCV. The problem is that the parameter names are common in the individual algorithms. As an example, the parameters for both *GradientBoostingRegressor* and *RandomForestRegressor* include

- n_estimators
- min_samples_split
- min_samples_leaf
- max_depth

I want to know that if I pass some values for these parameters in GridSearch, will they be used for both regressors simultaneously or I can specify the regressor separately?

Comment: You can't pass just `n_estimators` as a hyperparameter; instead, there will be multiple versions of that, e.g. `abr__n_estimators` and `gbr__n_estimators`.

Comment: @BenReiniger Can you point me to the documentation for this? Did not find that in scikit learn's documentation.

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#composite-estimators-and-parameter-spaces
You can call `model.get_params().keys()` (in this case, `model` is your stacking regressor) to fetch the parameter names to be sure.